# Как плавно изменить прозрачность объекта(из видимого в невидимое)? (с помощью Jquery)

Tags: css, jquery

```
header{
    z-index: 999;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

нужно сделать css свойство background видимым
Я, скорее всего, неправильно написал код сверху. подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

**Js**

```css
.normal {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.hidden {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<div class="normal" onClick="this.classList.add('hidden')"></div>
```

**JQuery**

```css
.normal {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="normal" onClick="$(this).fadeOut()"></div>
```